# Couldn't find the toolbar option for stored procedure

Tags: heidisql

This may be a silly question but I'm unable to find the stored procedure toolbar in my HeidiSQL. Could anyone tell me how can I do that? I'm using HeidiSQL 7 version.

The below link demonstrate one stored routine editor but I couldn't find it in Version 7.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3826986/Creating-Stored-Procedures-in-MySQL-Using-HeidiSQL-4146s-Stored-Routine-Editor.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using HeidiSQL version 8.

In the left pane, right-click on a database or a table and select `Create new` → `Stored routine`.