# What causes the error java.sql.SQLException: cannot parse parameter definition :IN `device_id` CHAR(24)

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm calling a stored procedure from a java application, using a `CallableStatement`. I have many other `CallableStatements` that take the exact same 24 Chars as input without any problems (on different tables).

Also, when I manually run the procedure in HeidiSQL and type in the parameters to be saved it saves the data without any issues.

I've tried setting the `CallableStatement` with the parameter name and the index with no success.

The whole Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: cannot parse parameter definition :IN `device_id` CHAR(24)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.CallableParameterMetaData.readMetadata(MySQLCallableStatement.java:193)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.CallableParameterMetaData.readMetadataFromDBIfRequired(MySQLCallableStatement.java:63)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.CallableParameterMetaData.getParam(MySQLCallableStatement.java:237)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.CallableParameterMetaData.getName(MySQLCallableStatement.java:278)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLCallableStatement.nameToIndex(MySQLCallableStatement.java:493)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLCallableStatement.setString(MySQLCallableStatement.java:843)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.CallableStatementJavassistProxy.setString(CallableStatementJavassistProxy.java)
    at com.app.data.DataDAO.saveBootloaderStateObject(DataDAO.java:222)
    at com.app.firmware.server.UsartReconnectProcessor.processBytes(UsartReconnectProcessor.java:135)
    at com.app.firmware.server.WorkerRunnable.run(WorkerRunnable.java:57)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My code:

```
    public void saveBootloaderStateObject(
            SavedBootloaderState bootloaderStateObject) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = database.getConnection();
            log.debug("DEVICE ID: " + bootloaderStateObject.getDeviceId());
            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection
                    .prepareCall("{call saveBootloaderState(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
            callableStatement.setString("device_id", bootloaderStateObject.getDeviceId());
            callableStatement.setString("current_state", bootloaderStateObject.getCurrentState());
            callableStatement.setInt("current_position", bootloaderStateObject.getCurrentRecordPosition());
            callableStatement.setString("build_date_new", bootloaderStateObject.getBuildDate());
            callableStatement.setString("build_time_new", bootloaderStateObject.getBuildTime());
            callableStatement.setString("build_date_old", "TODO");
            callableStatement.setString("build_time_old", "TODO");
            callableStatement.setObject("saved_bootloader_state", bootloaderStateObject, Types.BINARY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            log.info("An SQLException occured!", e);
            closeDbConnection(connection);

        }

    }
```

The stored procedure:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO firmware_upgrade_recovery (device_id, current_state, current_position, build_date_new, build_time_new, build_date_old, build_time_old, saved_bootloader_state) 
VALUES (current_state, current_position, build_date_new, build_time_new, build_date_old, build_time_old, saved_bootloader_state);
END
```

The parameters are declared in the same order, and the types are `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `INT`, `VARCHAR` x4 and `BINARY`

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Looks like you have a problem in your storedprocedure `saveBootloaderState`

Comment: Di you try using parameter indices instead of names, i.e. `callableStatement.setString(1, bootloaderStateObject.getDeviceId())`, `callableStatement.setString(2, bootloaderStateObject.getCurrentState())` etc?

Comment: If that doesn't work then maybe you could share the signature of the stored procedure as well. [`CallableParameterMetaData`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/1.1.7/org/mariadb/jdbc/MySQLCallableStatement.java#CallableParameterMetaData) expects a certain format from the parameter definitions (`PARAMETER_PATTERN` variable in the linked source).

Comment: yes, I tried that, no difference. @Jens but it works fine from HeidiSQL.  Maybe I'll just scrap it and start again.

Comment: updated now. This is very frustrating. I've got loads of other procedures that work fine with similar parameters

Comment: You didn't include the signature which is the relevant part as that's the information parsed in `CallableParameterMetaData.readMetadata()`. One thing worth trying would be to remove the backticks (`) from the identifiers, recompile the procedure and try again (not sure if the regex matches when you have backticks in the identifiers, even though it's valid MySQL syntax).

Comment: I haven't used HeidiSQL, but [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024331/couldnt-find-the-toolbar-option-for-stored-procedure) has some info about creating stored procedures. I would try re-creating the procedure without backticks in the parameter identifiers (`IN device_id CHAR(24)` etc), if that's possible using that UI.

Comment: thanks! I'll check it out.

Comment: Well, after many hours of messing around I prefixed the procedures input parameters with "in", so I have `in_device_id` and so on. That appears to have solved the problem, although I've no idea why, as I don't have to do that with other procedures I've written for the same server :-/ At least it works now. If anyone has any idea what the cause might have been I'd love to know!

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never resolved the issue properly, I just prefixed in input parameters with 'in'.

so device_id became in_device_id, and so on.

It's the best I can do right now.